# Scroll button on Logitech mouse won't left/right "click"

Tags: finder, mouse, click

I just got a Mac and couldn't stand the Mighty Mouse it came with, so I got a nice little Logitech wireless USB mouse (Model M325).

It's much nicer, but when I have Finder in column views and go to back up or go forward directories with the middle mouse button (tilting the scroll button  left and right until it clicks), it doesn't work.

I'd understand if Apple just didn't support 3rd party mice, but I have another (much older) USB mouse (Logitech RX 650), and it works as expected out of the box...

Any ideas? Seems like the new Logitech mouse should work fine. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple offers basic mouse support out of the box for just about any USB or Bluetooth mouse. However, the center button's right/left clicks are not considered standard mouse functionality. Therefore in order to utilize these buttons, a driver or special piece of software is required. Unfortunately Logitech does not provide any special software compatible with both the Mac and the mouse model you have. [This support thread](http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Mice-and-Pointing-Devices/MAC-OS-driver-support-for-M325-mice/td-p/753298) on Logitech's site includes a comment from a Logitech employee confirming this.

I have seen reports that [Better Touch Tool](http://blog.boastr.net/) supports certain Logitech models, to fill in the gaps that Logitech left in designing this mouse. It's worth a download, as it's free.

Comment: Appreciate it. It's weird that the really old Logitech mouse works out of the box and the newer one doesn't.

I'll give BTT a shot.

Comment: Wow! Better Touch Tool works perfect. I set up the Normal Mouse tab so left-scroll-click was linked to "Page Before" and right-scroll-click was linked to "Page After" (or something similar). Now everything works great. Thanks man!

Comment: Thanks for the help !! Better Touch Tools is amazing !! Kudos !!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my reply from the [Logitech Support Forum](http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Mice-and-Pointing-Devices/MAC-OS-driver-support-for-M325-mice/m-p/845922#M40641)

> I have SteerMouse, a utility to utilize/alter the mouse features on a Mac, which I used with one (or more) previous mouses I have had.  SteerMouse can be tried for free, but costs $20 for permanent use.  But SteerMouse cannot see the M325 if the Logitech driver is resident.
>
> So here is what worked for me:  First, I install LCC as usual, then I configure my Logitech wireless keyboard with it, and make sure the M325 moves the pointer (if not use Logitech Unifying Software to get it going).  Then I uninstall Logitech with the LCC Uninstaller.  Restart.  Now the keyboard is still configured as I want, but SteerMouse can see and configure the M325.
>
> The drawback is that I will have to go through the install/iuninstall step if I ever want to re-configure the keyboard.  Or if I ever add some other Logitech device to configure.

Answer (score 0):

One work around is to go to Preferences->Mission Control and there set mouse actions for Expose (Mission Control), Show Application Windows or Show Desktop or Dashboard.

Note that in your mouse left tilt is Mouse Button 4 and right tilt is Mouse Button 5.