# Enable scrolling using hot key and left mouse button

Tags: keyboard, mouse, macos

I have a Logitech M705 (marathon performance plus) mouse, plus the MK 710 Keyboard, I use Logi Options on macOS Big Sur and Mojave (2 separate macs). Recently I started to have pains on my hand /wrist and correlate them to be using frequently the Middle mouse button to scroll through many tools such as IDEs and Chrome.

I want to be able to push a hot key – such as <kbd>Alt</kbd> (= <kbd>⌥ option</kbd>) – and to enable scrolling by (left button) clicking and dragging the mouse to any direction of the screen. Is this achievable?

*Ideally I would like to avoid writing scripts or install 3rd-party tools, but I'm open if there is no other choice*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is based on a 3rd-party software **Karabiner-Elements** and uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Mouse motion</kbd> to scroll wheel.  (*credits to [timeSmith](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/372021/116146)*)

1. Download [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/)*
2. Install it and open it (see [docs](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/getting-started/installation/) about *Security & Privacy System Preferences*)
3. On **Devices**, make sure (only) the Logitech devices are selected: `USB Receiver (Logitech)` - mouse and keyboard **type**
4. Import these [mouse_motion_to_scroll](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/#mouse_motion_to_scroll) rules (browser > Karabine)
5. Enable only `Change control + mouse motion to scroll wheel (rev 1)` **Complex modification** rule
6. Tune the `speed` to `200%` or as desired
7. *(optional)* On **Functional** > select `Use all F1, F2, etc as standard function keys` to avoid changing the behavior of these keys.

---

* *tested on macOS Mojave (10.14.x), using [v12.10.0](https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements/releases/tag/v12.10.0); for Catalina (10.15.x), use [v13.7.0](https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements/releases/tag/v13.7.0)*

Comment: Related questions: [enable-scrolling-with-middle-button-drag-in-os-x](https://superuser.com/questions/303424/can-i-enable-scrolling-with-middle-button-drag-in-os-x) [scroll-button-on-logitech-mouse-wont-left-right-click](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/89768/scroll-button-on-logitech-mouse-wont-left-right-click) [configure-control-scroll-wheel-to-increase-decrease-zoom-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30192884/is-it-possible-to-configure-control-scroll-wheel-to-increase-decrease-zoom-in)